# How can I get SSMS to provide Auto Completion for SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, editor, ssms, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to identify a SQL Server Management Studio option (when writing/running queries) that provides table/column auto-complete functionality in the query editor. Unfortunately, SSMS seems to stop giving you Intellisense when you're connected to a SQL Azure database. Is there any way to fix this?

Are there any options, hacks, plugins or anything else that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Release of SQL Server Management Studio V17.2 now support Intelliscence so no need to have any other tools for this.

Please note that this will only work in case of SQL Server Authentication, that means logged in using SA Instance.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3100677/ssms-2016-would-be-nice-to-have-intellisense-on-azure-sql-databases

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this one as it seems to be the "better" answer now for most people going forward. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. This will for sure help others.

Comment: I've just installed SSMS 17.4 and Intellisense works sometimes... It works at first, but when I add a JOIN or a table alias, it's gone...

Comment: Well this is among common issues faced by other people. Please use troubleshooting from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/troubleshooting-intellisense

Comment: Nope, neither authentication method can handle even trivial DRI join hints.  Even Microsoft's own contributions to mssql-cli in Python are better.

Answer (score 3):

I've finally stumbled upon an option. It's non-ideal but it is certainly a huge step in the right direction!

[dbForge SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) is a SSMS plugin that replaces SSMS's built-in Intellisense with its own auto-complete engine. This is a HUGE improvement when connected to SQL Azure, but so far the free version feels like a step backwards when connected to traditional SQL Server instances. Overall, I think we're going to prefer using this over not using it. I'll come back in a couple days to report how well (or not) it's going.

At least it's an option, though!

Comment: Let us how you get on! I have recently encountered the same problem. I'm hoping MS will soon provide intellisense support for SSMS + SQL Azure.

Comment: @QF_Developer - So far, this is working well enough for us. It's about what we expected: MUCH better when working against an Azure database and less ideal when working against a SQL Server database. However, the latter is more because of what we're used to - it's not a cut-and-dry worse thing. Some people will actually like it better. And I may too, over time.

Comment: 3 and a half years later and I still find myself using SQL Complete. SSMS is better these days but SQL Complete still is a considerable improvement and I find myself keeping it handy.

Comment: This is going to be a lifesaver.  I love DevArt.  Their CodeCompare is my favorite diff tool by far.

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio have enabled basic IntelliSense for Azure SQL, but it isn't avalaible easily.

You have to click on table, select from drop menu `DROP AND CREATE TO -> New query window` and then IntelliSense will work. If you simply use `New query` it will not.

Comment: For my coworkers it works. Anyway, it does not matter anymore, Azure SQL V12 should work out of box with SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: Very dangerous, I wouldn't recommend this

Comment: @Ginden - I take it this did not turn out to be true since I still don't have Azure Intellisense in SSMS 2016.